# How can I get the list of broken link of one drive by Powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, onedrive

How can I get the list of broken link of one drive by Powershell script? I have got the copy link Url by

```
 $linkShortCut = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]::CreateAnonymousLink($ctxClient, $itemUrl, $false)
                        $ctxClient.ExecuteQuery()
```

But could verify whether the link is broken or not?

Answer (score 0):

Possible but rather complicated.

You can check out this article from Pieter Veenstra describing how to use PowerShell to check broken links in SPO:

[Office 365 – Check your site for broken links in SharePoint Online – Part 1.](https://sharepains.com/2017/10/05/office-365-check-your-site-for-broken-links-in-sharepoint-online-part-1/)

[Office 365 – Check your site for broken links in SharePoint Online – Part 2.](https://sharepains.com/2017/10/09/office-365-check-your-site-for-broken-links-in-sharepoint-online-part-1-2/)

Comment: This don't help me anyway. I have Link copy the "help.docx" document Url form abc oneDrive and paste this copy Link Url to xyz oneDrive. Then I deleted the "help.docx" of the source abc oneDrive.

Then I used the below script:

try {
if ((invoke-webrequest "https://xyz-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mike_agreeyademo_onmicrosoft_com/ERlaLzc72whFkwchvk5Z7dsBJCHEQkvj1Ox_0hxFZD3g_w" -DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -Method head).StatusCode -ne 200){
Write-Host “Broken link:” $value.Url
}
}
catch
{
Write-Host “Broken link:” $value.Url
}


In this case I don't get Broken link.